# XQuery: Return an empty element rather then element with data

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an XML document(catalog.xml) as following

```
<catalog>
 <product dept="WMN">
  <number>557</number>
  <name language="en">Fleece_Pullover</name>
  <colorChoices>navy black</colorChoices>
 </product>
 <product dept="ACC">
  <number>563</number>
  <name language="en">Floppy_Sun_Hat</name>
 </product>
 <product dept="ACC">
   <number>443</number>
   <name language="en">Deluxe_Travel_Bag</name>
 </product>
 <product dept="MEN">
  <number>784</number>
  <name language="en">Cotton_Dress_Shirt</name>
  <colorChoices>white gray</colorChoices>
  <desc>Our <i>favorite</i> shirt!</desc>
 </product>
</catalog>
```

when I evaluate

```
doc("catalog.xml")//product
```

I get the result as :

```
<product dept="WMN">
 <number>557</number>
 <name language="en">Fleece_Pullover</name>
 <colorChoices>navy black</colorChoices>
</product>
<product dept="ACC">
 <number>563</number>
 <name language="en">Floppy_Sun_Hat</name>
</product>
<product dept="ACC">
 <number>443</number>
 <name language="en">Deluxe_Travel_Bag</name>
</product>
<product dept="MEN">
 <number>784</number>
 <name language="en">Cotton_Dress_Shirt</name>
 <colorChoices>white gray</colorChoices>
 <desc>Our<i>favorite</i>shirt!</desc>
</product>
```

we have the requirement to read data from xml, the file size may exceed 1GB. we need to display only nodes with its attributes but inner data is not required.

Is there any way to get only tags like below.

```
<product dept="WMN"/>
<product dept="ACC"/>
<product dept="ACC"/>
<product dept="MEN"/>
```

Comment: i think you need to write XSLT for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XQuery you can just construct a product element and return the value of the dept attribute.

```
for $dept in doc("catalog.xml")/catalog/product/@dept
return <product dept="{$dept}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Functionally, this is easy enough, as shown by @chrisis. The question is whether this solution will work with a 1Gb input document, and that depends on the implementation. Many implementations (if the input is raw XML in filestore, rather than a database) will try to build a tree in memory, and this could require anything up to 10Gb of memory, depending on how compact the tree representation is. Really you need a streaming solution.

XSLT 3.0 has built streaming into the specification, and you can get guaranteed streaming for this with the code

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="product">
  <product dept="{@dept}"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Whether you can get an XQuery product to use streaming is entirely product-dependent, because the W3C specification has nothing to say on the matter. Saxon, for example, does have some capabilities for streaming in XQuery, but they rely on vendor extensions to the spec.

Comment: Good point. I tend to work with XML databases where memory is managed for you so I didn't pay attention to the files sizes.